# Tick checkboxes from a join table

Tags: php, mysql

I need a way to compare a join table from a loop I have showing a list of categories from another table and tick them if the category id matches the doc id.

Here is my current function which I am struggling with:

```
<?php

function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc; // database connection
    global $id; // id from the url


    $q = "SELECT * FROM doc_cat_join LEFT OUTER JOIN cats ON cats.cat_id = doc_cat_join.cat_id;";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    var_dump($r);

    $currentDoc = $id;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '" '.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
        </ul>';
    }

    }

?>
```

So I have three tables:

```
docs
  doc_id

cats
  cat_id

doc_cat_join
  id
  doc_id
  cat_id
```

My code above lists out the rows from the cats table and creates checkboxes. When I am in a doc editing it I need a way in my code above to take the doc id form the url (which I can do) and then perform a comparison on the join table? and tick the checkboxes if a rows exists of the doc_id and the cat_id here is a visual of my doc_cat_join table:

[image]

I believe my JOIN is the part that is causing me the issue but not sure on how to cure this issue?

If I do a var_dump on $r inside of the loop I get this..

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(7) ["lengths"]=> array(7) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(7) [6]=> int(51) } ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

**UPDATED**

this update reflects the suggest answer below but I am still having some problems:

```
<?php

function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc; // database connection
    global $id; // id from the url


    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats AS c LEFT JOIN doc_cat_join AS dcj ON c.cat_id = dcj.cat_id AND dcj.doc_id = $id";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    $currentDoc = $id;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = $row['id'];

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '" '.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
        </ul>';
    }

    }

?>
```

Here is the query that deletes and inserts the boxes that are ticked:

```
$q = "SELECT doc_id FROM docs WHERE doc_name='$dn' AND doc_id != $id";

        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0) {

            // Make the query:
            $q = "UPDATE docs SET doc_name='$dn', doc_content='$dc', doc_owner='$do' WHERE doc_id=$id LIMIT 1";


            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            if ($r) {

            // CODE TO DELETE ROW FROM DOC_CAT_JOIN    
            $q = "DELETE from doc_cat_join WHERE doc_id = $id";
            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            //AND THEN...    

            // CODE TO INSERT BACK INTO DOC_CAT_JOIN    
            $query = "INSERT INTO doc_cat_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES "; 
            $cat_ids = $_POST['cat_id']; 
            $length = count($cat_ids); 
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat_ids); $i++) { 
            $query.='(' . $cat_ids[$i] . ',' . $id . ')'; 

            if ($i < $length - 1) 
            $query.=','; 
            } 

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is:

**for given document ID show me a list of all categories and check the ones that are linked to given document** - is that correct?

In order to achieve that, you need to change the query you run. You want to fetch all categories and join some additional data from **doc_cat_join** if it exists for given category and docID, so the query you need is:

```
SELECT * FROM cats AS c LEFT JOIN doc_cat_join AS dcj ON c.cat_id = dcj.cat_id AND dcj.doc_id = <doc id from URL>
```

This way you'll get all categories data and columns from **doc_cat_join** table. If given category is not linked to given document, the columns from **doc_cat_join** will be NULL, otherwise they will contain correct values from that table.

In order to define $checked value, you can just do

```
$checked = $row['id'];
```

ID column from **doc_cat_join** will have a value set only if given category is linked to given docID.

**UPDATE:** The way you handle user input in PHP introduces serious security vulnerability - please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: So I tried your suggested fix and you fully understand what I am trying to achieve here - the problem I face now is that if I tick the boxes it just deletes them from the doc_cat_join and does not insert as it was before - and of course not showing the ticked boxes

Comment: The code above just gets data from the DB, it doesn't delete any data. Some other parts of your code must be doing that, but I can't help here without seing the rest of the code.

Comment: So that has been updated to show you how it works, so when i come to edit a doc it deletes firstly then inserts back into the join table when editing.

Comment: Could you dump $_POST['cat_ids'] and delete $query that is being generated? There are multiple things that could go wrong here.

Comment: where would you like me to make the dump?

Comment: In the last line, instead of " mysqli_query($dbc, $query);" do var_dump($_POST['cat_id']);var_dump($query); and let me know what you got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82372/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Comment: I get this `array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } string(59) "INSERT INTO doc_cat_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES (,10),(,10)"`